# SQL multi-part identifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my simple sql code. When in executed its throw and error.

**The multi-part identifier "product_hscodes.hscode" could not be bound.**

```
select DISTINCT mi.*,csq.contract_code
  from master_items mi
  join contract_shipment_qty csq on csq.item_code = mi.code
  join contract c on c.code = csq.contract_code
  join master_item_products mp on mp.master_item = mi.id
  join hscode h on h.code = product_hscodes.hscode
 where csq.shipment_id = 6
   and csq.contract_code = '046V-12-A04-05'
   and mi.code = 'M165'
   and h.code = '12345'
```

Comment: i think you forgot to join `product_hscodes` table.

Comment: No, i have tried. if i added to "FROM" its throw "mi.code" nor found

Comment: then why are you joining this `join hscode h on h.code = product_hscodes.hscode`?

Comment: Show your code with `product_hscodes` in `FROM`. I think you, have an error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not joined `product_hscodes` table.

```
from master_items mi
join contract_shipment_qty csq on csq.item_code = mi.code
join contract c on c.code = csq.contract_code
join master_item_products mp on mp.master_item = mi.id

join product_hscodes 
     on product_hscodes.fk = <primary table>.pk //<<Have you joined this table?

join hscode h on h.code = product_hscodes.hscode
```